# Java - Validation when user enters string into boolean

Tags: java

Currently working with web-services and doing validation, would like to have a better error message when user enters in JSON block for Boolean:

JSON:

```
{
      "name": "GAWA",
      "isFree": true
}
```

As expected, works fine since meeting the criteria for a Boolean. However the issue emerges if a user will enter a string.

```
{
      "name": "GAWA",
      "isFree": "gwge"
}
```

Current Error Message:

```
"message": "Can not deserialize value of type java.lang.Boolean from String \"rwtrt\": only \"true\" or \"false\" recognized\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@7e9abd26; line: 14, column: 2] (through reference chain: com.velatt.dartentitlements.dto.SiteDTOExternal[\"useAppEntitlements\"])"
  },
```

I would assume it's an if statement along the lines of:

```
 if (isFree ...) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot create a person without a valid boolean");
        }
```

Any help of what condition I could put it?

Edit: I am not looking to change it so if they enter true it will be converted to a Boolean, I simply want to reject all strings in favour of better error message.

Comment: Validate against a schema before deserializing. Something like [this](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator) will generate good messages; you just need to maintain a schema.

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks for the suggestion but I mean any strings, I want it to reject all possible strings and produce a more user friendly error message.

Comment: if("true".equals(isFree.trim().toLower()) ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot create a person without a valid boolean");
        }

Comment: @vengets See my response, want to reject all strings

Comment: `if(isFree instanceof String){...}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the object `isFree` is an instance of the String class.

Try this:

```
if (isFree instanceof String) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot create a person without a valid boolean");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will reject all other datatypes except Boolean

```
if (isFree instanceof Boolean == false){
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot create a person without a valid boolean");
}
```

Comment: `isFree instanceof Boolean == false` is redundant use `!(isFree instanceof Boolean)`